# Posting a suggestion when I'm not sure about the answer

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer

can I answer a question even if i am not 100% sure it is correct and not get negative points for that answer? like a suggestion. Is there any special way to post as a suggestion?

Comment: An answer should be an answer, partially or fully. Suggestions as comments work better.

Comment: @Sobrique Users under 50 reputation (such as hitman4890) cannot comment, probably hence the cause for asking this question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Wait until you gain the [Comment Everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege and post your suggestion as a comment.

Don't be afraid of down votes, consider them as a "constructive criticism" and learn from them. We're here to help and get help, most of my knowledge here I gained were from suggestions and correction of my answers.

Comment: This is a good response, but I would suggest adding one note: if you leave a comment with a suggested answer, please check back in with the question periodically, so that if the OP says that your comment worked as a solution, you can repost it as an answer. I think this is especially important when the OP is newer on SO, as they may not know how to use the @ notation in their comments to let you know they liked your answer.

Comment: Another thing that could be helpful is that if a person down votes your answer, they can atleast leave the reason for down voting. It helps beginners (like me) to know what we might have missed and gain through their knowledge.

Comment: If I see answers that do this, should I be expected to flag it?

Comment: @mcadam331 it really depends on the answer

Comment: this is wrong. if you're not sure about your answer, either (a) post it as an answer (peer review will soon sort it out), or (b) don't post it at all. putting it in the comments is wrong. comments are not for answers. why would you avoid peer review when you're not sure? that's when you _want_ peer review!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Do you want 15 suggestions or actual solutions? If suggestions are in answers then there will be too much irrelevant data. The rest community will decide.

Comment: @RohanKandwal That is wrong. The site is geared up to having multiple answers that can be voted on (and edited) and let the best/most correct ones rise to the top. That's, like, the entire model of the site. It is not, by contrast, geared up to have solutions given in the comments section.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings There's a difference b/w solution and suggestion, please understand that. The answer in question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20772591/1979347 Please see the edit history.

Comment: @Rohan A suggestion is just a solution you think might be wrong. It is stupid to post that while dodging peer review. Absolutely stupid. And pointless. Use the answer section *that is what it is there for*. Or post nothing at all. Someone who actually knows the answer can do it instead. Have a good day

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Don't want to argue further, good day.

Answer (score 6):

The way I would figure (and have been posting), if you kind of sort of suspect that the correct answer is something like X, post X as a comment (once you have the ability to do so).

If, on the other hand, you're about, say, 85% sure X would do the job, but you'd have to do 30 minutes of boilerplate coding and compiling to be sure, just post it as an answer already: you can't be 100% sure no matter what, so just take any corrections you need humbly and work them in if possible.

The exact threshold is up to you, but basically, when your mental state goes from "I suspect this" to "I'm pretty sure of this" is when you switch from comment to answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of cases that might be useful to distinguish, here.

The first is when you do not know enough, but think you see where the problem is. This might be best as a comment, but if you post it as an answer, you should at least note that you are unable to verify that you are correct.

The second is when you know enough, but the post is simply not detailed enough to be answered "correctly" - because the poster did not include enough detail, or there are troubleshooting steps that should be done. In this case, if you can ask for clarification, that's great - but posting an answer with a good explanation of what the different possibilities are is sometimes even better, for future reference.

In either case, make sure to follow up and check that the original poster didn't clarify and obsolete your answer, or provide the detail that was needed.