# When I have an 'answer' to my own question but am not 100% sure about it

Tags: discussion

This isn't really a duplicate of [Posting a suggestion when I'm not sure about the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281010/posting-a-suggestion-when-im-not-sure-about-the-answer), but it's quite similar.

In one of my [current questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712122/implementing-class-based-query-query-property-in-a-zope-transaction-manager-sy) a comment has led me to improve my code as stated in the question. The comment in question suggests one possible issue with my current code, and a follow-up comment suggest a way to test the issue. Based on both, I now have updated code which passes that test.

If another person were to post my (now updated) code as an answer, I would be happy with the help, but would not accept it as an answer as the overarching question of 'global' and 'testability' is not yet really answered. This indicates that it is at least possible that my updated code should be posted to my own question as an answer.

Alternatively I could edit my initial question. As it's a new question with no answers yet I think that's fairly undestructive, but I'm unsure as to the semantics of what a significant modification to the question is for/would achieve.

Comment: Ultimately, post self-answers if you believe they are useful. If it is a partial answer, and also useful, post it. As for updating the question, if you do that, then posting an answer with the same would be redundant. It is a matter of judgement whether you should update the question (making it a new question), or add an answer and ask a new question.

Comment: (The acid test for me is whether there are answers already. If there are, then only do minor updates to the question, since you must be careful not to invalidate an existing answer, as that is unfair on someone who has helped you. However, since you have no answers so far in this case, you could just adjust the question.)

Comment: Thanks @halfer I'll do that. Sounds like you have an answer there though would you please post an answer rather than comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The broad strategy I have is that one should post something if it might be useful for others. Thus, if you are not sure about your material, or it is partial, consider still posting it anyway, and just couch it in the appropriate cautions. If you can come back to the post when you have done more research, to improve uncertain material and fill in incompletenesses, that would be ideal.

I would refrain from posting partial or uncertain material if it is very short though - that is probably best just as a comment. You can post it as a full answer if and when you have more material to offer. The guiding principle here is quality and substantivity.

You asked whether partial answers would, instead, be better as question edits. The answer is "possibly", if you can shift the emphasis of the problem (and the title) to the new question state. However, if you have already received answers, make sure that your edit does not invalidate that work; if it does then you may annoy people trying to help you, and someone may roll back your question to an earlier state, possibly with a downvote for having created editing work.